# How to install/setup GridDB in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, database, ubuntu, time-series, griddb

Besides using DOCKER, downloading CentOS, and setting up GridDB, How to setup a GridDB client and server on Ubuntu? Its docs have RPM/YUM methods only.
I want to do a quick explore GridDB using Python to interface with JayDeBeApi on Jupyter-Notebook

```
 pip3 install griddb-python --user
```

Since the above command has **griddb server** and **python client** installation **prerequisite** so Is there any (say) way to install or some docs?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ubuntu with the current docs: https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/using-apt/

It seems as though that since this question was asked until now, you can install GridDB on Ubuntu using APT:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.0 multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list'

$ wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install griddb-meta
```

And that will install GridDB, the C_Client, the JDBC connector, and the CLI tool